# Port Ubuntu Touch using Windows 10 ubuntu bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu-touch, windows-10, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm trying to port Ubuntu Touch to my phone using Windows 10 bash. After many try, i stuck on building the test image for Nexus 4 to check possible it's or not. And every time after starting building:

```
make -j4 # Or any other amount of threads
```

After aprox 3-5 minutes I got error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

To check where this fault happens I'm try to install the **gdb** package with no luck.

So, for this reason I have 3 questions:

1. How to successfuly install gdb package?
2. If it's not possible, how to debug this error?
3. ... it's possible to complete this job in Windows 10 subsystem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On clear Ubuntu 16.04 i got same error. How to fix it?